# Is it legit to post a self answer with (almost only) a link to another self answer of yours?

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers, self-answer

It might sound confusing, but let me explain.

Going through the "Low Quality Posts" queue, I have stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21682634/5366641).

It is an almost a *link only answer*. However, there is some kind of explanation, which sounded to me, as if the author of the answer is mad at the OP for asking a question, which has already been answered. Technically, because of the explanation, it should look OK.

So, investigating further, I followed the link and it is indeed an answer by the same author (actually a self answer).

Everything looked pretty usual at this point, until I realized that the answer I was reviewing is actually a self answer. This surprised me and made me ask:

Is such situation legit?

Comment: Would marking the q as duplicate not have been appropriate in that case?

Comment: @Thornkey, most certainly. However, it is an ancient one (from 2014) and a year later someone noticed that and commented it (possibly flagged it as well, I could not know that), but in any case, there is no consequence, since it is there and still open.

Comment: And he's super mad on the OP since he couldn't remember the same this for the second time.

Comment: @HasanCanSaral, :) I was like - whom is he/she speaking to?

Comment: This came up in my queue too.  I recommended deletion, and probably should've flagged one of the questions, but the whole thing was so bizarre I wasn't even sure which question to flag.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They ask, comment and answer all by themselves in that question...

Both are self-answers, and came at the same time, although the questions came two weeks apart. I imagine they got stuck with the problem, resolved it by the time of the second question, and finally realized it applied to the first question as well.

I'd flag for moderator atention. To me, the best result is the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21682634) gets deleted/converted to a comment and that fist question gets marked as a dupe to the second one (that already have answers).

But better to let a mod to make the call, since doing that would require several steps that would take too long for the community to make. (And converting to comment is simply not possible for the community).

Answer (score 10):

An "answer" that consists of little more than a link to an answer of another question indicates that the questions are duplicates, and one should be closed as a duplicate of the other.

Answer (score 2):

It looks very odd doesn't it.

I suspect that what happened was this:

- The OP posted a (frankly) rather poorly written question which is basically a "please help me" that didn't properly describe the problem.
- The OP did some more research and solved the problem, and added a self answer.
- Nobody noticed.
- The OP then tried to recoup his effort by writing a better Question on the same topic, and self-answering ... with an answer than basically links to his previous self-answer.

Of course, what he should have done was edit the *original* Question to make it clearer what the problem was.

What to do?  Raising a moderator flag is one approach.  However, it probably requires a tag expert to figure out if the Questions and Answers are worth salvaging.  Maybe deletion of both Questions would be the most practical solution.

> Is such situation legit?

Certainly it isn't desirable.  The result is a mess that really doesn't help anyone much.

Legitimate?  Well the OP didn't actually break any rules.  (Apart from the rule of common sense ...)